# Is it possible to pass username and password in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, terminal

Hi I'm using makefile to do lots of compiling and remote works.

In many occasion I would need to type in username and password for remote connection, VPN, code upload and other stuffs.

May it be possible to use makefile to auto type in the credential information?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Typically, the *better* way to pass credentials in a build process is to have an SSH agent -- maybe even communicating with a smartcard (like a yubikey) to keep the credentials in hardware that can't be copied, so they can't be stolen/misused (and a developer can't be impersonated without stealing their key, or at least generating a tunnel through to whatever hardware they have it plugged into). As the answer by Stephen says, `make` isn't involved in any of that; whether you use a ssh agent and whether you use makefiles are completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: See https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/, in combination with https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/ -- or just the latter if you aren't going the hardware-backed route. (Agent forwarding lets you have a private key stored on, or backed by hardware plugged into, the developer's own host, but make it usable by whichever build server is actually running a build on that developer's behalf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the role of `make` to do this kind of thing.  So there is no special support in a `Makefile` for handling credentials.

However, if you can get a shell script to do the "auto-typing" or provide the required credentials some other way, then you should be able to use the same approach in a `Makefile`.

We can't advise you on how the script would work, because you have given no actual details of the commands etc that you are using for remote access.

But if you are using ssh from a Linux box, you could use public key authentication and `ssh-agent` and avoid the problem entirely.  This would be a lot more secure than:

- using user / password auth at all, and
- embedding passwords in your makefiles ... for someone else to find when they steal your laptop or whatever.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! Usually I'll use ssh, and using openvpn to get internet access to restricted area(china). There are several servers that I can choose, all of them same password. Due to the service, the configuration files change regularly, so it is better to use shell method instead of changing config files....